# Give a example of 2$\times$2 matrix A such that A has one independent eigenvector while $A^2$ has two independent eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Give a example of 2$\times$2 matrix A such that A has one independent eigenvector while $A^2$ has two independent eigenvectors.

I do found a explaination here.
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015306/2-times2-matrix-a-such-that-a-has-one-independent-eigenvector-while-a2)

And I followed it to make X as $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ and get the A as $\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$. Not really sure whether I am right.

Yeah, I checked that post and my problem is I still don't know how to get the A. Because it says x should be nonsingular so I tried $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ but it seems it's wrong..

Comment: If $A=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$ then $A^2=\mathbf{0}$, so every $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is an eigenvector

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem. I read that post and don't know how to get an example matrix.